# Python Pandas ffill with if statement?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numba

I have the following timeseries measuring changes between a starting and ending point in two columns. I would like to compute the column `l` using a vectorized approach instead of an iterative in Pandas recording the path from start to end. Is there a simple way to compute the column please? `ffill()` and other fill techniques naively do not appear to solve the empty between a starting and ending position. Is there a way to condition `ffill/bfill` to help solve this problem?

Note: `s` and `e` correspond to starting and ending positions. I want to build a sequence where `l` is only between the `s` and `e` positions but not including the start position (and not including where there are no start and ends).

Example shown below, rows 0-2 we want to fill `l` with ones excluding the very first. Also want to be sure we don't have ones for rows after until we have another `s`.

```
    s   e   l
0   1.0 NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN 1.0
2   NaN 1.0 1.0
3   NaN NaN NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN
5   NaN NaN NaN
6   NaN NaN NaN
7   1.0 NaN NaN
8   1.0 1.0 1.0
9   1.0 1.0 1.0
10  1.0 1.0 1.0
11  NaN 1.0 1.0
12  NaN NaN NaN
13  NaN NaN NaN
```

Thank you and help is very much appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected result? I still don't know how to use `s` and `e` to get `l`

Comment: Look at row 0 through row 2, we want to fill `l` with ones between that range including the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good approach for these *hard to vectorise* problems is to go with `numba`. By using `numba` the code gets compiled to down to `C-level`, so this should perform very well on large dataframes. By speficying the numba types in the signature we get ahead-of-time compilation and further boost the performance. Here I'm setting the input type to `float64`, for another input `dtype` change accordingly.

```
from numba import njit, float32

@njit('float32[:](float64[:,:])')
def ffill_conditional(a):
    flag_col0 = 0
    out = np.full(a.shape[0], fill_value=np.nan, dtype=float32)
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        if a[i,0]==1. and flag_col0==0:
            flag_col0 = 1
            from_col0 = i+1
        elif a[i,1]==1 and np.isnan(a[i+1,1]) and flag_col0==1:
            till_col1 = i+1
            out[from_col0:till_col1] = 1.
            flag_col0=0
    return out
```

---

Checking on the shared example:

```
a = df.values[:,:2]
df['l'] = ffill_conditional(a)

print(df)

     s    e    l
0   1.0  NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN  1.0
2   NaN  1.0  1.0
3   NaN  NaN  NaN
4   NaN  NaN  NaN
5   NaN  NaN  NaN
6   NaN  NaN  NaN
7   1.0  NaN  NaN
8   1.0  1.0  1.0
9   1.0  1.0  1.0
10  1.0  1.0  1.0
11  NaN  1.0  1.0
12  NaN  NaN  NaN
13  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Great solution! Thank you for the help!